# How to create new package in an old package in Myeclipse with tree shape structure

Tags: myeclipse

I want to create new package in an old package in Eclipse with tress shape structure like this:

```
Unit6
     Session1
             Part1
```

I managed to create it yesterday, but now it don't work, the structure is like this:

```
Unit6.Session1.Part1
```

I've tried some method such as change the "Page Presentation" to "Hierarchical", but it did't work.I'm a fresher of this IDE, please help me out.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know what's going on. It just because I create only one package in the old package "Unit6", so MyEclipse present in "Flat" way by default. When I create the second package in the old package "Unit6", MyEclipse present in "Hierarchical" way which I set. I'm so stupid!